# When transforming and using groupby, data is missing from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have data with Spouses on separate rows. Each spouse shares the same ID. When IDs match, I sum values and move the spouse row to a column, so spouses now share one row.

Everything is working as expected, but when an ID matches, the spouse data moving from row to column is not working.

Input

```
   ID  Position  Title  First  Last  SpTitle  SpFirst  SpLast  Address    Value1  Value2  Value3
0  456 HoH       Mr.    John   Doe   NaN      NaN      NaN     123 street  10      NaN     30
1  456 Spouse    Mrs.   Jane   Doe   NaN      NaN      NaN     123 street  10      NaN     30
2  789 HoH       Mrs.   Jane   Doe   NaN      NaN      NaN     456 road    100     200     300
3  789 HoH       Mrs.   Jane   Doe   NaN      NaN      NaN     456 road    400     500     600
4  789 Spouse    Mr.    John   Doe   NaN      NaN      NaN     456 road    NaN     10      30
```

Desired Output

```
   ID  Position  Title  First  Last  SpTitle  SpFirst  SpLast  Address    Value1  Value2  Value3
0  456 HoH       Mr.    John   Doe   Mrs.     Jane     Doe     123 street  20      NaN     60
1  789 HoH       Mrs.   Jane   Doe   Mr.      John     Doe     456 road    500     710     930
```

Current Output:

```
   ID  Position  Title  First  Last  SpTitle  SpFirst  SpLast  Address    Value1  Value2  Value3
0  456 HoH       Mr.    John   Doe   NaN      NaN      NaN      123 street  20      NaN     60
1  789 HoH       Mrs.   Jane   Doe   NaN      NaN      NaN      456 road    500     710     930
```

Why is data for Spouse information being dropped from my dataframe?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read csv and combine sheets
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Sheet.xlsx", sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)

# Drop blank IDs
df = df[df['ID'].notna()]

# Insert Spouse columns
df.insert(loc = 10, column='SpTitle', value = '')
df.insert(loc = 11, column='SpFirstName', value = '')
df.insert(loc = 12, column='SpMiddleName', value = '')
df.insert(loc = 13, column='SpLastname', value = '')
df.insert(loc = 14, column='SpBirthDate', value = '')
df.insert(loc = 15, column='SpGender', value = '')

m = df.Position.eq("Spouse")

df.loc[m, ["SpTitle", "SpFirstName", "SpMiddleName", "SpLastName", "SpBirthDate", "SpGender" ]] = df.loc[
    m, ["Title", "First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Gender", "Date of Birth"]
].values

df[["Value 2019", "Value 2020", "Value 2021", "Value 2022", "Fund 2019", "Fund 2020", "Fund 2022", "Fund 2021"]] = df.groupby("ID", as_index=False)[
    ["Value  2019", "Value 2020", "Value 2021", "Value 2022", "Fund 2019", "Fund 2020", "Fund 2022", "Fund 2021"]
].transform(np.sum, min_count=1)

df[["SpTitle", "SpFirstName", "SpMiddleName", "SpLastName", "SpBirthDate", "SpGender"]] = df.groupby("ID", as_index=False)[
    ["SpTitle", "SpFirstName", "SpMiddleName", "SpLastName", "SpBirthDate", "SpGender"]
].transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())

df = df[~m].drop_duplicates()

df.to_csv("C:/Users/data.csv", index = False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [456, 456, 789, 789, 789],
        "Position": ["HoH", "Spouse", "HoH", "HoH", "Spouse"],
        "Title": ["Mr.", "Mrs.", "Mrs.", "Mrs.", "Mr."],
        "First": ["John", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "John"],
        "Last": ["Doe", "Doe", "Doe", "Doe", "Doe"],
        "SpTitle": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        "SpFirst": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        "SpLast": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        "Address": ["123 street", "123 street", "456 road", "456 road", "456 road"],
        "Value1": [10.0, 10.0, 100.0, 400.0, np.nan],
        "Value2": [np.nan, np.nan, 200.0, 500.0, 10.0],
        "Value3": [30, 30, 300, 600, 30],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Group values
df = (
    df.groupby(["ID", "Position", "Title", "First", "Last"])
    .agg({"Address": lambda x: list(x)[0], "Value1": sum, "Value2": sum, "Value3": sum})
    .reset_index()
)

# Add new columns SpTitle, SpFirst, SpLast
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df.loc[df["Position"] == "HoH", :].reset_index(drop=True),
        df.loc[
            df["Position"] == "Spouse",
            ["Title", "First", "Last", "Value1", "Value2", "Value3"],
        ]
        .rename(
            columns={
                "Title": "SpTitle",
                "First": "SpFirst",
                "Last": "SpLast",
                "Value1": "SpValue1",
                "Value2": "SpValue2",
                "Value3": "SpValue3",
            }
        )
        .reset_index(drop=True),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

# Update values
df["Value1"] = df["Value1"] + df["SpValue1"]
df["Value2"] = df["Value2"] + df["SpValue2"]
df["Value3"] = df["Value3"] + df["SpValue3"]

# Cleanup
df = df.reindex(
    columns=[
        "ID",
        "Position",
        "Title",
        "First",
        "Last",
        "SpTitle",
        "SpFirst",
        "SpLast",
        "Address",
        "Value1",
        "Value2",
        "Value3",
    ]
)
```

```py
print(df)
```

Output:

[image]